# URL Naming and resolving

Tags: url, dns

I have a website with a URL in the following format: https://word.word.org.uk/word/

This website is a portal used by customers and the usage spikes and is focused mainly around 3 - 4 consecutive days in the month. The problem is that sometimes the page doesn't load **at all** for some customers and their connection keeps dropping. Please note that it's not all customers that report the issue, only some. They report issues with loading the website and also failed logins. So it seems the website is down intermittently, I think. I'm really not sure what the problem is so I'm wondering if the naming of the URL itself might be causing issues when resolving?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: have you monitored your web server performance during the spikes? Chances are the question is off topic here.

Comment: No, there is no conceivable way in which the naming could cause those issues. If that was the problem, they wouldn't have a problem with loading or using the site, they'd have a problem _finding_ the site.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl what exactly do you mean by _finding_? As in resolving the DNS? Because that's what I meant by "loading". So you're saying the naming might be the issue in that case?

Comment: @TheLyrist Yes, the performance is high so it makes sense that some users experience slower performance but I don't understand why the page wouldn't load at all.